Undead Uniforms
My Glorious Armed Forces have recently developed the ability to raise the dead as skeletal warriors armed with black-powder weapons.  The Nation and its competitors are basically at the level of late 1700s/early 1800s Europe.  The skeletons are perfectly clean upon creation (whatever flesh they had on them is consumed by a black fire that we are 99.9% certain has a scientific explanation when the skeleton warrior is created) and are fully articulated with zombie-like intelligence.  They will follow orders, but have essentially no free will and will stand perfectly still when not under orders.
To differentiate them from other nation's skeletal warriors I'd love to give them a cloth uniform and hat like a normal infantryman of the Napoleonic Wars or Seven Years War. They would not need boots, and don't need the uniforms for any practical reason outside of easy battlefield identification. The question is, would their uniforms last significantly longer than uniforms issued to flesh-and-blood human soldiers?  The power that animates them doesn't affect anything else, so the clothing (as well as the military equipment like straps, cartridge box, etc) would sit directly on the bones.  They are treated exactly like human troops so they're marching/drilling (for the necromancer-officer's benefit not their own) during the day and usually standing in barns/outside/wherever at nights or when not actively being ordered about.
If it makes a significant difference I'd be willing to treat the bones as eternally sterile rather than something somebody might have to clean every once in a while.  If minor modifications to the normal uniform or leaving off parts of it would mean much longer use by my skeletons that would also be acceptable.
I do NOT want painted skeletons.  His Majesty's Government doesn't have unlimited funds and doesn't want to re-clothe skeletons every six months but it does have a certain sense of style so painting/modifying the skeletons themselves are not acceptable answers.

I probably should have asked this before answering, but are these skeletons just for fighting, or will they be digging ditches and whatnot between fights? This period is significantly before trench warfare. I presume that they'd be carrying packs, just so the humans don't need to. I don't believe that latrines existed prior to mid-1800's.

@RobertRapplean Yes and no, trench warfare actually started during the US Civil War.  Shovels were not yet standard issue for every soldier; so, it saw limited use, but there were cases, especially towards the end of the war of shallow earthworks being dug and logs stacked to set up temporary entrenchments prior to an expected battle. The success of these tactics informed military doctrine in future wars to make shovels standard issue.

Instead of using all of these additional resources on troops that don't need protection from the elements and to avoid taking resources from other aspects of your Nation, just run your Skelly Soldiers through a dye dip! Set up a bath tub with the coloured dye of your choice, dunk for a wee bit and let air out. The dye soaked into the skeleton could be assumed to have decent wear characteristics and means no restrictions to movement or weight to slow them down or get snagged on anything.

OP clearly stated: I do NOT want painted skeletons.

@Nosajimiki earlier than that - Crimea, for example, precedes the American Civil War by about a decade, and there were significant precursors for many centuries

@ChrisH I was mistaken, I did not know about their use in Crimea (the History Channel got this one wrong).   This just reinforces my point though that soldiers were digging trenches in the mid-1800s.

Wear of uniforms
As a historical reenactor, I've had quite a bit of experience with period uniforms over the years. Generally speaking, most of the wear on a wool uniform of the type used in the period occurs due to rubbing up against stuff. Since the undead will be doing more or less the same activities as common meatbags, this sort of wear will occur at roughly the same rate. Thus, no, their uniforms will not last substantially longer than their living counterparts.
EDIT: In fact, they will almost certainly last significantly less time. The living can patch holes and repair seams with their handy-dandy housewives; the undead probably lack the intelligence and fine dexterity needed to do so.
That said, there are some areas where less wear will occur. The undead do not need to take off their uniforms. Moreover, they do not need to—ahem—"use the powder room", so their pants do not need a fly, allowing an undivided front as in modern elastic-waistband pants.
Also, while the logistics folks will probably have the uniforms tailored down a bit to save material (especially in the legs and arms), chances are they will still hang more loosely than equivalent meatbag uniforms. This means that things such as splitting of the crotch seam will not be as common.
Uniform specifics
You did not directly ask about this, but there are a few things that I would like to cover anyway. First off: the hat.
Back in the Napoleonic era, most armies did not wear hats; instead, they had a type of tall cap called a shako. The necromantic skeletons' lack of soft tissue would make keeping one on very difficult. Since the skeletons do not need to take their uniforms off, perhaps the shako could be nailed on.
Second, the cartridge and cap boxes would present a problem. Most (if not all) period uniforms attached these to a wide leather pistol belt, which would then be cinched around the wearer's true waist (which is roughly at the level of most people's belly button). Skeletons do not have a waist, and cinching the belt directly around the spinal column increases the chance it will break if the skeleton falls. Instead, consider the method used in the WWI-era Imperial German uniform. In this system, the belt rests on clips in the frock coat (which are disguised as decorative buttons.) It is further supported by a strap around the soldier's neck. While a strap around the neck would be a no-go for the same reason as cinching the belt directly to the spine, a set of suspenders with the ends clipped to the belt would serve roughly the same purpose.
Speaking of suspenders, the set keeping the soldier's pants up (military uniforms did not use belts for that purpose until much later on) would need to wrap around the clavicle, as otherwise they would slip off.

They would not need boots

Wrong. Without boots (or possibly brogans, although those were more common during the American Civil War era), your skeletons will severely lack traction. Moreover, their foot bones will quickly erode away, rendering the undead army useless.

+1 but also worth exploring the stated employment as using muskets or rifles and the implications thereof on uniform.  A skeleton has no fleshy bits to brace the butt of a longarm against on the shoulder.  They also mass less than a dozen kg, which means that recoil at shoulder height would knock them over - but with no organic eyes there is no benefit to shooting from the shoulder anyway.  Therefore, need to have a uniform element that lets them brace against the pelvis for "hip shooting" with enough padding to prevent shattering said pelvis.

"Since the undead will be doing more or less the same activities as common meatbags." I contest this presumption. Soldiers aren't constantly busy. Once the camp is set up, they spend a lot of time drilling, practicing, and socializing. Skeletons won't be doing that, or anything that involves sitting, laying, leaning, crouching...

Don't use classic uniforms instead use sleeveless tabards.
The things that wear out the fastest are the arms and legs, they are also the majority of the cost of such clothes. A tabard on the otherhand can be made from a single piece of cloth with minimal work, drastically reducing cost and they will minimize the parts that will experience the most wear.
For best results, use hard wearing linen canvas, which can handle being exposed to the weather, is very durable and skeletons won't care if its uncomfortable.


This is a Frame Challenge

His Majesty's Government doesn't have unlimited funds and doesn't want to re-clothe skeletons every six months but it does have a certain sense of style...

The Royal Exhequer completely agrees! And that's why in a secret meeting with the quartermaster general it was decided to present to that most Royal of Majesties...
... the simple reality of economics.
Even if the Court could afford to dress all those really expendable and fairly easy to come by skeletons, why lavish such cost? It's one thing to parade your troops in the nation's finest. They have as much pride as the mothers, fathers, dignitaries, and even the monarch! But does a skeleton feel pride? Is anyone really going to stand there and sing the national anthem as they rattle mindlessly by? Heck no! It's not as if the skeletons feel cold or anything, right? Am I right? So, rather than scare little children by parading the undead in front of them (no matter how well dressed), the Royal Exchequer suggests this:
Let's tie a pennant to the skeleton's spine.
Cheaper to produce, cheaper to clean, easier to re-aquire if the skeleton becomes, shall we say, imobilized... Pretty snazzy looking, too! All those pennants blowing in the breeze, which is hardly blocked at all by all those ribs!
A pennant, dread soverign. A pennant to balance national pride with the national treasury.

Every kingdom has many things that add a small bit of unhappiness to its population.
Too many such issues tends to have consequences.  Here, I'm not speaking of rebellion but more of the various subtle ways a citizen can help or sabotage a kingdom.  E.g., happy citizens are more likely to report issues (rather than saying, "not my problem") and tend to fight harder for the army.  Treating the skeletons of your own citizens with a bit of respect isn't free, but it might be worth it for a its impact the populance's respect towards the kingdom.

Yes, but treating skeletons with respect is not dressing them (skeletons look ridiculous wearing clothes) but donning them the Most Glorious and Illustrious Pennant of the Great Order of the Undead Knights of the King.

I get you, @Brian, but let one of those happy peasants receive a letter from their son complaining about the lack of good shoes and watch those same peasants start wondering why anything is being spent on a skeleton. I have to admit, I'm a bit biased right now because I'm inundated with so many political ads before the U.S. general election on Nov 5th that I'm wondering how many children could be fed, clothed and housed if the money was spent more wisely. Said another way, I'm not sure showing respect to what for all intent and purposes is a piece of artillery would spawn that much loyalty.

Are your 99.9% scientifically derived skeletons immune to their feet bones eroding whilst parading around all day? If not, you'll need something on their feet. Boots would add grip, but they sure are expensive. I might suggest something like skeleton horseshoes, which can be nailed straight through the foot and have the added bonus of sounding fantastic on a cobbled or tiled floor. Most battlefields of that era would be muddy fields anyway so that probably wouldn't negatively affect combat effectiveness.
While we're talking about grip, consider how your skeletons are going to hold and fire their weapons with bare hand and finger bones. They're likely to need at least cloth gloves for that purpose. Now what about the ammunition? They'll need pouches of powder and shot, or similar, and some way to store them. There are pros and cons of hooking said pouches inside the ribcage, though having the odd skeleton explode due to stray fire would be pretty cool.
Finally, consider that your skeleton army are considerably more durable than a human one, because (headshots aside) a pile of ambulatory bones is harder to hit - with shot or bayonet - than a live human. However, any human-like clothing or uniform would not be so lucky. Unless you reissued the uniform considerably more frequently than you reanimated skeletons, your bone corps would quickly end up clothed with ragged, hole-filled stuff. Wear and tear from walking around in it would be the least of your worries.

Wear and tear would still be the biggest worry, as, contrary to popular imagination, armies didn't (and don't) spend most of their time in battle, but marching, camping,  marching, drilling, marching, foraging, cleaning, mending, oh, and did I mention marching?


would their uniforms last significantly longer than uniforms issued to flesh-and-blood human soldiers?

Solely based on the consideration that clothes wear faster when they rub/chafe against harder surfaces and that bones are harder than any flesh and skin, the answer is a sound NO. Your z-uniforms won't last longer than h-uniforms under same usage conditions.

I think you're basically right, but the counter-argument is that skeletons are not sweaty and oily and slightly acidic, like live humans, so you won't have that...  Physical wear is almost certainly the more immediate problem, though.

The fact that skeletons stand still when "resting", instead of sitting/lying down like humans do, may help with preserving their uniform: less creasing, less tearing, etc...

Undead won't complain if you use less comfortable, longer lasting materials.

Yes a skeleton uniform will last significantly longer
Here are the factors which give increased uniform life.

Reduced number of laundry cycles. No matter how you clean uniforms, each time it is washed, the uniform's life will decrease. Comparing a skeleton to a human, the skeleton's uniform will need to be washed less frequently as it will typically only get dirty from the outside (while the human body will get dirty inside and out). Also, when the skeleton isn't being used, it just stands still, while your humans will still keep on moving and getting their uniforms dirty.
Lower activity in skeletons. The skeletons will move less in their uniforms and therefore will have less chance for a garment wearing event (rubbing, tearing, etc.) to happen.
The uniform need not be designed for comfort and could be designed to be more robust from a wear perspective.


+1 for pointing out that comfort is not an issue.  I recommend carving the hats out of wood, or making them out of tin sheet or similar, and painting them to look nice, and then gluing or riveting them in place.  Similarly, any additional pieces of clothing that are desired can be crafted for durability and reusability rather than comfort.

Cloth and or Leather will last a lot less time
When a human gets muddy, we stop to clean up at the next available opportunity.  When we are standing around in the beating sun or pouring rain, we seek shelter.  We don't need orders to do this, we just do it, and in doing so, we significantly increase how long our cloths last. Because your skeletons don't have any hyenine impulse, they will allow various conditions that can ruin a perfectly new uniform in a matter of weeks or even days.
Because they are drilling with their human counterparts, we can assume they are getting muddy, but I've ruined a number of canvas and leather work gloves by leaving them in the shed a few day after getting them dirty without cleaning them. The same is true of military uniforms.  Mud, especially if left in direct sunlight will quickly harden and crack cloth and leather.  Also, if your skeletons just hang out for hours on end in direct sun because an officer forgot to tell them to come in, even in clean uniforms, they will get sun bleached causing the color or their uniforms to quickly fade.
Lastly, bones are not soft like skin. When a skeleton bumps against a tree or a rock, there is no flesh to compress allowing the cloth to pass unharmed, it is literally caught between a rock and a hard place making it much more likely to rip under normal use.
So how should you uniform your skeletons?
Curaisses and metal helmets were still somewhat commonplace in during the Napoleonic Wars. Although these could rust eventually from poor maintenance, they have no fibers to permeate and crack, and have no issue with the sun.  The can be decorated with inlaid metals, and/or painted with the oil or resin based paints of the time period which would help protect the armor from rust and could last many years of outdoor regular use without any particular maintenance.

Also, the assumption that your skeletons don't need boots is outright wrong.  That is the one article of clothing they absolutely do need.  Human feet are protected by thick pads of skin and flesh, and even with this, we need boots.  Marching directly on bone feet will cause a lot of wear and tear to your skeletons; so, even if they do not feel it, they will certainly notice it when their feet fall aparat. So, for this I would recommend some manner of buskin boot or sandal.  Buskin boots don't keep your feet warm or dry like modern military boots, but they do not get ruined as easily because the cords can expand and contract with getting wet and muddy and they are much cheaper to replace which made them the preferred footwear of farmers who had to work out in wet fields for centuries after closed toe shoes became more common in other parts of society.


These uniforms would have to be weather-resistant, but otherwise they would get little wear. Clothing only gets damaged when it gets squeezed between two surfaces, when flexed a lot, or when washed. Most of the wear on your daily clothing happens in the washing machine. That's why the cuffs on your pants and shirts fray before the knees and elbows wear through.
Your biggest wear points would be the knees, and you could dress them in shorts. Unless they're crawling on hands and knees, you'll get about the same wear as with clothing on a mannequin. A mannequin that stands outside in the rain and snow and wind, but still...
Addendum: Consider flocking, or just hats and shoulder pads.
